# How to call function from different javascript page in php

Tags: php

how to call JavaScript from any page of PHP

`<a href="javascript:toggleEditor(\'' . $l['id'] . '\');`

I want to know how exactly the javascript page was called

Comment: Your code is correct. Can you clarify ? What is your problem ?

Comment: `<a href="javascript:toggleEditor('<?php echo $l['id']; ?>')">...</a>;` ?

Comment: Maybe put in file and use: `<script src="toggleEditor.js"></script>`.

Comment: @KevinLabécot i want to know how  correctly to call javascript function from different php page

Comment: @mukrishnaa Include the javascript file?

Comment: You have to include the javascript source on every page that wants to execute that js code. So do as @bloodyKnuckles suggests on each of your pages

Comment: @RiggsFolly is without include of page is it not work?

Comment: @RiggsFolly is correct.

Comment: If you want to run a piece of javascript on a web page, you have to have that js code available to that page, so either hard code it in each page (not good idea) or make it into a toggleEditor.js file and use the `<script src="toggleEditor.js"></script>` syntax to load it to each page you want to run it on in the <head> section. Or better still just before the final `</body></html>` tags so it does not slow down page loading.

Comment: @RiggsFolly but in that above page i was post as a question doesn't any inlcude or <sript> present